# Change popup message depending on form input

Tags: wordpress

I have a form where the customer can enter some information about where they live and what they want to buy. However we do not offer the product to everyone, so if a customer enters a zipcode in the field that we don't accept, a popup should display a message (Sorry, we do not offer this to you), but if they enter a correct value, a popup with a new form should be shown instead so that they can proceed with the full form. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have 2 popup forms on your site. One for showing the error and another one for showing the form.
Let's assume that you have stored the accepted zipcodes somewhere(database). Once they enter the zip code in the field, just compare the entered zip code with the accepted zipcodes. If the entered zip code is correct then trigger the popup which has the form. If the entered zip code is incorrect, then trigger the popup which shows the error.

Do let me know if it works for you.